# Updating the values of groups in a column from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I know how to update a dataframe's column using the related keys and values from a dictionary, but what is the best way to update the ***values of several groups in a column*** from a dictionary?

So, one way to do this is by doing a groupby and then reading the group values from the corresponding keys in the dictionary. However, this takes too long for my dataset which has 14M rows and 125000 'match_id's.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'match_id': ['m1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3'],
                   'name':['peter', 'mike', 'jeff', 'john', 'alex', 'joe', 'jeff', 'peter', 'alex', 'li', 'joe', 'tom', 'mike', 'john', 'tom', 'peter'],
                   'rank': [4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 4],
                   'rating': [1200, 1300, 1600, 1550, 1150, 1540, 1340, 1300, 1390, 1290, 1450, 1650, 1420, 1490, 1320, 1410]})

dict1 = {'m1': [5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 3], 'm2': [4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 1], 'm3': [2, 1, 4, 3]}

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
grouped = df.groupby('match_id', sort=False)
for id, dfg in grouped:
        dfm = dfg.copy()
        dfm['new_rank']= dict1[id]
        df_new = pd.concat([df_new, dfm], sort=True)
```

This creates a new column 'new_rank' where the values are extracted from the dict1 for each match_id.

I also tried the ***map*** function but since it is not for groups, it just pastes the whole list of values for each match_id on each row.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

On a side note, this is the way I came up with the dictionary which calculates the new ranks based on the order of numbers in the 'rating' column (If you can also think of a better way to approach the whole thing, please let me know):

```py
dict1 = {}
grouped = df.groupby('match_id', sort=False)
for id, dfg in grouped:
    dfm = dfg.copy()
    dict1[id] = [len(dfm['rating'])-(sorted(dfm['rating'], reverse = False).index(x)) for x in dfm['rating']]
```

Comment: What is the logic of the dictionary you created? Can you explain it instead of just showing the code.

Comment: It is for another part of my code but can be discarded for this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I asked for the logic of the dictionary, is that we can solve the problem right there. You just want [`Groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['new_rank'] = df.groupby('match_id')['rating'].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
   match_id   name  rank  rating  new_rank
0        m1  peter     4    1200         5
1        m1   mike     3    1300         4
2        m1   jeff     1    1600         1
3        m1   john     2    1550         2
4        m1   alex     5    1150         6
5        m1    joe     6    1540         3
6        m2   jeff     2    1340         4
7        m2  peter     4    1300         5
8        m2   alex     3    1390         3
9        m2     li     1    1290         6
10       m2    joe     5    1450         2
11       m2    tom     6    1650         1
12       m3   mike     1    1420         2
13       m3   john     3    1490         1
14       m3    tom     2    1320         4
15       m3  peter     4    1410         3
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and was super fast! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, have a fast read about [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It can help you to ask the right question.